# How to iterate over basic blocks?

Tags: llvm

I want to add an instruction to each of my basic blocks, I can use LLVMAppendBasicBlock for that once a bloc is specified. But how to iterate over all basic blocks in a function ? Are there iterators for that in the LLVM API ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can simply use iterator over function like :

```
 for (Function::iterator b = func->begin(), be = func->end(); b != be; ++b) {
BasicBlock* BB = b;
....
}
```

Comment: For me this returned an error but `BasicBlock &BB = *b;` compiled.

Comment: Where does ``be`` come from?

Comment: This is giving Error. Says `cannot convert`.

Comment: If you want to use pointer, it should be `BasicBlock* BB = &*b;`

Answer (score 3):

There's

```
LLVMBasicBlockRef   LLVMGetFirstBasicBlock (LLVMValueRef Fn)
```

and

```
LLVMGetNextBasicBlock (LLVMBasicBlockRef BB)
```

The documentation for `LLVMGetFirstBasicBlock` says:

> Obtain the first basic block in a function.
>  The returned basic block can be used as an iterator. You will likely eventually call into `LLVMGetNextBasicBlock()` with it.

So call `LLVMGetFirstBasicBlock` once per function, and then `LLVMGetNextBasicBlock` repeatedly until you've gone through all the basic blocks of that function (juding by [the source](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/Core_8cpp_source.html) you'll get a `nullptr` when that happens).

Comment: An interesting approach. Nowadays, `getEntryBlock()` of `llvm::Function` would be more suitable to get the first block.

Answer (score 1):

It’s quite common to have a Function instance that you’d like to transform in some way; in particular, you’d like to manipulate its BasicBlocks. To facilitate this, you’ll need to iterate over all of the BasicBlocks that constitute the Function. The following is an example that prints the name of a BasicBlock and the number of Instructions it contains:

```
Function &Func = ...
for (BasicBlock &BB : Func)
  // Print out the name of the basic block if it has one, and then the
  // number of instructions that it contains
  errs() << "Basic block (name=" << BB.getName() << ") has "
             << BB.size() << " instructions.\n";
```

FYR: http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-basicblock-in-a-function